# How to sort a dataframe based on idxmax?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    A  B   C
0   1  2   1
1   3 -8  10
2  10  3 -20
3  50  7   1
```

I would like to rearrange its columns based on the index of the maximal absolute value in each column. In column `A`, the maximal absolute value is in row 3, in `B` it is row 1 and in `C` it is row 2 which means that my new dataframe should be in the order `B C A`.

Currently I do this as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3, 10, 50], 'B': [2, -8, 3, 7], 'C': [1, 10, -20, 1]})
indMax = abs(df).idxmax(axis=0)
df = df[np.argsort(indMax)]
```

So I first determine the indices of the maximal value per column which are stored in `indMax`, then I sort it and rearrange the dataframe accordingly which gives me the desired output:

```
   B   C   A
0  2   1   1
1 -8  10   3
2  3 -20  10
3  7   1  50
```

My question is whether there is the possibility to pass the function `idxmax` directly to a `sort` function and change the dataframe `inplace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC the following does what you want:

```
In [69]

df.ix[:,df.abs().idxmax().sort_values().index]
Out[69]:
   B   C   A
0  2   1   1
1 -8  10   3
2  3 -20  10
3  7   1  50
```

Here we determine the [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html#pandas.DataFrame.idxmax) in the [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html) values, sort the values and pass the index to index the df.

As to sorting in place you can just assign back to the df.

For a pre `0.17.0` version the following works:

```
In [75]:
df.ix[:,df.abs().idxmax().sort(inplace=False).index]

Out[75]:
   B   C   A
0  2   1   1
1 -8  10   3
2  3 -20  10
3  7   1  50
```

Comment: That gives me `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'sort_values'`. Which pandas version are you using?

Comment: Ah, latest version use `sort` instead

Comment: When I use `sort`, I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'` Seems I should update my pandas version... Ah, never mind, should have checked your edit - now it works fine. So I upvote it and might accept it late ron, depending on the other answers' quality.

Comment: by default `sort` is in place so it returns `None` so you need to pass `inplace=False` it's one of the few methods where `inplace=True` but it's deprecated in the latest version

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly, but it seems to work using [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
import numpy as np

>>> df.reindex_axis(df.columns[list(np.argsort(abs(df).idxmax(axis=0)))], axis=1)
    B   C   A
0   2   1   1
1   -8  10  3
2   3   -20     10
3   7   1   50
```

Comment: That indeed works, so I upvote it as well. @EdChum's version, however, is more what I had in mind.

Comment: :-) Well, FWIW, not only do I think his answer is better here - his answers are just better in general.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative anyway; I always enjoy getting several answers which broaden my knowledge :)